# Best practice for handling large objects in mobile applications

Tags: android, ios

I have a mobile application with a lot of "overview"-screens i.e. different forms of lists of objects.

These objects are fairly large. The Model (struct or class) has some 70-80 attributes.

All of those attributes are rarely needed at once, especially in lists where said objects occur frequently where you would typically just show 8-10 attributes.

When going into a detail screen of the object, it would consume a lot more attributes.

So, how would you typically handle a situation like this:

1) Create two classes. One that has a subset of the other and use the subset in lists and the full class in the detail view

2) Create only one class, but only fetch the attributes needed for the list and fill the rest of the attributes with "dummy values" when fetching data for lists and only fetch the full object when displaying it in detail

3) Only have one definition of the class and always fetch everything for it. It's 2017, the data is probably still smaller then your average webpage

If you need more information, please ask for it.

Comment: How many of those objects will typically be in the list? Also, are the objects obtained from a web service or are they stored locally?

Comment: X to start with, then when reaching bottom, we fetch X more. X is typically somewhere between 20-50 objects. Always from a web service.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely make the use of Model/ POJO classes for the same.
    Like we use functions in modular programming, you can create more than one Model class unlike Creating one single class with all attributes.You can use the POJO class as per the attributes required.

```
For example:-

    class student{
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String street;
    String pincode;}

**can be converted to :-
`
class student{
StudentName name;
StudentAddress address;
}
class StudentName {
String firstname;
String lastname;
}
class StudentAddress{
String street;
String pincode;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering data received from web service is persisted and queried from SQLite database.

when data is in the database you can use one to one relationship. for e.g

let's say you have model/POJO as, in which you show users data as a list.

```
class User {
    //basic info showed in the list
    int userId;
    String name;
    String emailId;
}

class UserDetail {
    int id;
    int userPassportId;
    int userId; //foriegn key to user table
    .....
    // other nessesary details
}
```

SQL equivalent

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    emailId TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE userDetails(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_passport_number TEXT,
    user_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(id) 
);
```

so now when you are showing items you can just query data for all users which will give you basic user information which you may want to show in UI.

and when you go to detail page you can them make the query using user id to get the associated details.

```
SELECT * FROM userDetails WHERE user_id = user_id_recived;
```